# $y = \ln(p+qe^x)/x$, solve for $x$

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation, problem-solving, lambert-w

$$y = \frac{\ln(p+qe^x)}{x}.$$

$p$ and $q$ are constants.

Express $x$ in terms of $y$.

I believe I have to use Lambert W function, but I'm stumped.

Thinking help is needed. Thank you very much!

Comment: This is just $w^y=p+q w$, a general trinomial, for which this site has some solutions

Answer (score 1):

If $y=\ln r$, this is equivalent to $r^x=p+q~e^x$, which, unless either *r* is a rational power of *e*, or $pq=0$, does not possess a closed form expression, not even in terms of the [Lambert *W* function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).